Proving the Nested Compact Set Property
There’s this theorem in my analysis book that I want to prove, which states that:
If
$k_{1} \subseteq k_{2} \subseteq k_{3} \subseteq ...$
Then the intersection
$\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}k_{n} \neq \varnothing$
My idea was to show that $k_{n}$ contains its supremum, since all the sets are compact and thus are bounded and closed:
$k_{1}$ is bounded $\implies$ $k_{n}$ is bounded for all n $\in$ N
$\implies$ sup($k_{n}$) exists for all n $\in$ N
$k_{n}$ is closed for all n $\in$ N $\implies$ sup($k_{n}$) $\in$ $k_{n}$ for all n $\in$ N
Thus the intersection is non empty because every $k_{n}$ is non empty
Is this correct? If not, where did it go wrong?

I think your statement is trivial since $k_1 \subset \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}k_{n}$ you may want to ask Cantor's intersection theorem?

There are some issues with your theorem statement. You are probably referring to the following:

Let $\{ K_n \}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}^+}$ be a nested decreasing sequence of compact and non-empty subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. (By nested decreasing, we mean $K_1 \supseteq K_2 \supseteq \dots$.)  Then $\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{Z}^+} K_n$ is non-empty.

In your statement, you neglected to assume that each $K_n$ is nonempty, which is obviously essential. You also reversed the order of the set inclusions.
To prove the statement, we can start by showing a more general fact:

Let $\{ C_n \}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}^+}$ be a nested decreasing sequence of closed and non-empty subsets of a compact space $X$. Then $\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{Z}^+} C_n$ is nonempty.

The proof is straightforward. Assume the hypotheses and assume for the sake of contradiction that $\bigcap_n C_n$ is empty. Since $C_n$ is closed, then $U_n = X - C_n$ is open. We also have by applying De Morgan's Laws that
$$X = X - \emptyset = X - \bigcap_n C_n = \bigcup_n (X - C_n) = \bigcup_n U_n$$
That is to say, the collection $\{ U_n \}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}^+}$ constitutes an open cover of $X$. Since $X$ is compact, that cover has a finite subcover $\{U_1, \dots, U_N\}$. Since $\{C_n\}$ was nested decreasing, then $\{U_n\}$ is nested increasing. Therefore, $U_N = \bigcup_{i = 1}^N U_i = X$, which implies $C_N = X - U_N = X - X = \emptyset$, a contradiction.
This fact can be applied to prove your theorem by taking $X = K_1 \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and the sequence $\{C_n\} = \{K_n\}$. We cannot take $X = \mathbb{R}$ because $\mathbb{R}$ is not compact, but $X = K_1$ is compact by hypothesis. Of course, we also need that each $K_n \subseteq K_1$ is closed, but that follows from the fact that compact subspaces of Hausdorff spaces (which $K_1 \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is) are closed. See item [3] here for a quick proof of this fact. The result of your theorem follows directly.
For a direct proof of your theorem, the fact that "every $K_n$ is non-empty" is not sufficient to conclude that the intersection is non-empty. In fact, $K_n$ is non-empty by hypothesis. I would proceed using sequences. For each $K_n$, select $a_n \in K_n$. Since $a_n \in K_1$ for each $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ (by the decreasing nested property), then $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{Z}^+}$ is a sequence of elements in $K_1$. Since $K_1$ is compact, there is a subsequence $(b_k)_{k \in \mathbb{Z}^+}$, where $b_k = a_{n_k}$, that converges to some element $a \in K_1$. The element $a$ is an obvious candidate for an element in $\bigcap_n K_n$. Indeed, let $m \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ be arbitrary. The sequence $(b_{k + m})$ consists of elements in $K_m$ and converges to $a$. Since $K_m$ is closed, it follows that $a \in K_m$. Since $m$ was arbitrary, $a \in \bigcap_n K_n$, as desired.
